# How to build 2D lookup in python for none integer based indexes

Tags: python, collections

Still learning the basics in python and have been searching for similar examples but could not find a solution so here is my problem:

I am getting the following data as part of a large JSON object from an IoT service:

```
for structure in IoT.response['where']:
    for where in IoT.response['where'][structure]['wheres']:
        print structure + ' '+ where['where_id'] + ' ' + where['name']
```

Output:

```
structure                            location_id                          name
==================================================================================    
df6db2b0-36ac-11e3-b974-1231390b5549 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000100000001 Basement
df6db2b0-36ac-11e3-b974-1231390b5549 58eafc6e-8eab-4452-b48a-3a6f7f1004f7 Bathroom
df6db2b0-36ac-11e3-b974-1231390b5549 00000000-0000-0000-0000-00010000000d Bedroom
df6db2b0-36ac-11e3-b974-1231390b5549 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000100000003 Den
df6db2b0-36ac-11e3-b974-1231390b5549 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000100000010 Dining Room
df6db2b0-36ac-11e3-b974-1231390b5549 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000100000006 Downstairs
df6db2b0-36ac-11e3-b974-1231390b5549 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000100000000 Entryway
df6db2b0-36ac-11e3-b974-1231390b5549 00000000-0000-0000-0000-00010000000b Family Room
```

Question:

> How do I create a simple lookup where I can lookup the name of a location based on the none numeric structure_id and location_id to retrieve the name?

I have tried hashing the ids so I can work with numeric indices:

```
location[hash(structure)][hash(where['where_id'])] = where['name']
```

but I get a list index error:

```
list index out of range
```

I am sure I am missing something simple or obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mybe `location` is a list and not a dictionary. Use default dict to have a dictionary when you ask `location[structure]` items. Moreovere you don't need to use hash let dictionary to do its work.

```
import collections
location = collections.defaultdict(dict)
location[structure][where['where_id']] = where['name']
```

I'm not tested it but should work

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Gonna have to read up on collections and the defaultdict.